# SSRS Multiple parameters in single drop-down

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

I have a feeling I am probably out of luck on this one, but Is it possible to have more than one parameter in a single drop-down list on an SSRS report? For example, the drop-down could be titled shape/color, and when opened, the top of the list shows shapes, and one can be checked, then below that in the same list, is a list of colors, where one can also be checked. Possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really best to have separate drop-downs for each attribute, but within a single drop-down you would first set it to "Allow multiple values". You can setup your drop-down to be formatted so that the sections of available values are grouped together. Finally, you'll need to add a query or function to check that valid combinations were selected before trying to display the results. In other words, make sure only one shape was selected. You can set an error message with a visibility that toggles based on the selection. This is one method to do what you are looking for, but if you are new to SSRS, you will probably have more specific questions along the way. Once you have more details on a specific step, you can get help with that.

Comment: Thanks. That'll at least get me started. I agree separate drop-downs would be better, but the customer wants what the customer wants.